# Why is my WebBrowser control from ASP.NET not rendering a custom icon font properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, font-awesome

Here are two output examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8reaL.jpg

The first is CNN, which looks fine.  Doesn't have flash, but I don't care about that for my purposes.

The second is the Font-Awesome cheat-sheet page, here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Obviously that doesn't look so fine.

I sense there's either a compatibility problem or a timing problem, like maybe I'm not waiting for the right completion signal from the control.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    try
    {
        wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wp_document_completed);
        wb.Navigate(new Uri(m_board_url));

        int n = 0;
        while ((wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) && (n < LOOPS_TO_WAIT))
        {
            //  Also consider wb.IsBusy
            log_message(Convert.ToString((object)wb.ReadyState));
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
            n++;
        }
        log_message(Convert.ToString((object)wb.ReadyState));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log_message("exception!<br>" + e.ToString());
    }


private void wp_document_completed(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    wb.ClientSize = new Size(this.m_width, this.m_height);
    wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    m_bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Bounds.Width, wb.Bounds.Height);
    wb.BringToFront();
    wb.DrawToBitmap(m_bitmap, wb.Bounds);
    m_bitmap = (Bitmap)m_bitmap.GetThumbnailImage(m_thumb_width, m_thumb_height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
    m_bitmap_set = true;
}
```

I'd appreciate any ideas or suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: Start by identifying which "underlying" version of the control you are using as "The WebBrowser control is a managed wrapper for the ActiveX WebBrowser control, and uses whichever version of the control is installed on the user's computer." - MSDN i.e. does that version support @font-face etc.

Comment: It's behaved this way on both a Vista machine and a Win8.1 machine, each running IIS and .NET 4+.  The Vista machine shows a WebBrowser.Version of 9.0.8112.16563.  Presumably the 8.1 machine would be 11something.  Both browsers render the sites fine directly, it's only the WebBrowser control (or my code) that's misbehaving.  That was interesting to check, though, I didn't know there was a version property I could look at.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem too. After searching for a while I found the real solution. The problem is that webcontrol cant work with relative paths. By setting the woff for base64 encoded string I got it work. It looks like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ico';
  src: url('FontAwesome.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ico';
  src:  url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,<<base64_encoded_string>>) format('woff'), url('FontAwesome.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('FontAwesome.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it.

I spent a few hours trying different things and they all seemed to indicate that my code should be working.

I went to bed, got up today, spent a little more time playing, and was about to give up when I went back to the original test.  Local page was now working perfectly.

The only thing I had changed in that regard was to try installing the Font-Awesome .ttf and .eot (or whatever) files last night.

Those had not produced any change, but I shut down the machine when I went to bed.  Guessing the IIS reset on reboot somehow recognized the new fonts.

Font-Awesome's website is still broken in my viewer, and I'm not sure why, but I was trying to generate thumbnails on a webserver of pages that server hosts, and I sense that the installation technique only works locally, which is perfect for me.

If someone had to do this for a remote page, my sense would be that there's a permissions issue with installing a custom font through the browser control (or rendering it through GDI+).  So maybe try running IIS as an elevated user to test that.

Thanks!